# JavaScript setTimeOut doesn't seem to work like I expect

Tags: javascript

This is a simple JavaScript file which I run under Chrome (localhost...). What happens is that instead of the DIV background color set to Green and then to Red, it is just set to Red. The first setTimeout seems to be ignored.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Set TimeOuts</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script language="javascript">
function setBGColor()
{ 
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
setTimeout(setColor('yellow'),6000);
setTimeout(setColor('red'),6000); 
} 
function setColor(color)
{
    div1.style.backgroundColor=color; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" onclick="setBGColor()";>THIS IS THE COLOR TEST</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

BUT, if I put an alert(color) in the setColor function, I can see the div bgcolor go yellow first. Also, the 6000 is ignored as well. WHY?

Comment: Since you have setTimeout set to 6000 milliseconds for both functions, then they will both fire at the same time

Comment: Well you have written "yellow", so you probably won't get green (maybe on IE...). Also you have set both timeouts to the same value, so if you're real lucky you may get to see yellow (or green, whatever) one frame. You probably won't. Also as Quentin noted you are not using `setTimeout` right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> setTimeout(setColor('yellow'),6000);
> ```

You are *calling* `setColor('yellow')` and passing the *return value* (which is `undefined`) to `setTimeout`.

You need to pass it a function.

---

It is also important to note that `setTimeout` will cause a function to be called after a time. It doesn't make JavaScript sleep for that period.

```
setTimeout(setColor.bind(window, 'yellow'),6000);
setTimeout(setColor.bind(window, 'red'),6000);
```

… will call `setTimeout` at 0s, then call `setTimeout` again a fraction of a second later, then call `setColor('yellow')` at 6s and `setColor('red')` a fraction of a second after that.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { setColor("yellow"); }, 6000);` is also acceptable