# jquery timeout inside loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a json which contains list of serialized objects. And I want to walk this json and show messages from it one message per 2 seconds and then stop. 
I did it this way:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: basename+'/getUnprocessedList/123',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function (data) {
        for(var i=0, keys=Object.keys(data), l=keys.length; i<l; i++) {
            console.log('hit '+i);
            setInterval(processMessage(data[i]),2000);
             }}
});
```

But nothing working there, setInterval just ignored, all messages displayed at once, like no any timeout. I tried $.each, setTimeout, nothing works. What's wrong there?

Comment: `processMessage(data[i])` immediately calls the function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770286/javascript-settimeout-doesnt-seem-to-work-like-i-expect regarding how you're calling `setInterval()`, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue regarding the use of the variable `i`.

Answer (score 2):

Too many errors to count in this one line:

```
        setInterval(processMessage(data[i]),2000);
```

Correct version:

```
setTimeout((function(i){return function(){processMessage(data[i])}})(i), 2000*i);
```

Your problems:

- You're invoking the function immediately -- wrap it in a function
- `i` will go out of scope by the end -- wrap your function in a closure
- Use `setTimeout` with staggered intervals instead, to make it easier to keep track of `i`

Comment: Thanks, just checked - it writes hit+i 5 times, then waits, then all 5 messages at once. No consequent messaging so far :(

Comment: @avalon You included the `2000*i`?

Comment: yes, sorry, now I realized it works. Thank you that much! setTimeout((function(i){return function(){processMessage(data[i])}})(i), 2000*i); - this works :))) wohaaaa!!

Comment: @avalon If that's too many anonymous functions for your liking, i posted an alternate answer that may be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for loop, you can do your own looping in the `setInterval`.

```
success: function (data) {
    var i=0, keys=Object.keys(data), l=keys.length;
    var t=setInterval(function(){
        processMessage(data[i]);
        if(++i==l){clearInterval(t)}
    }, 2000);
}
```

This will repeat every 2 seconds, and stop when it reaches the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're invoking the function immediately in the `setInterval` call - to pass a function, you omit the `()` - but since you need a param - use an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() { processMessage(data[i]) },2000);
```

And you'll probably run into the issue of `i` being wrong now (because `i` will be the last iteration at the time of running, so wrap that in an IIFE)

```
(function(i) {
    setInterval(function() { processMessage(data[i]) },2000);
})(i)
```

OR - if you can, use `let` in your `for` loop:

```
for(let i=0, keys=Object.keys(data), l=keys.length; i<l; i++) {
    setInterval(function() { processMessage(data[i]) },2000);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. Removed DV.

Comment: The third one is out of scope

Comment: Thanks, nothing works from you suggested. I just checked it

Comment: @Derek, why do you not post your own solution ?

Comment: @Scimonster's solution works perfectly fine, no need for me to write my own